# Intent for Samsung Galaxy TAb A software update(Android OTA)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow, samsung-mobile-sdk

What's the intent to check software update on Samsung galaxy tab A(Marshmallow)? I was using "android.settings.SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS" , but it returns only system update. 
On tablet settings,the path to software update is Settings->About device->Download updates manually

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found was through intent-filter

`<intent android:action="android.settings.SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS" />`